# Exposing WCF to other application such as UBS

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

I'm a new to WCF and have no knowledge on exposing WCF for other external application which built by other technology (not .net)
I'm required to create a wcf service and expose it to a UBS application.
This ubs application will call the wcf service so that it can send file(excel) to my wcf service.

In most tutorial I have encountered or searched, the wcf service is created within a .net application.
I wonder, how can i expose my wcf to the public/other application/UBS application?

Answer (score 0):

This is not WCF, but have you tried http://www.asp.net/web-api?  You can expose data as JSON or XML, which can be consumed by applications other than .NET